# Qt programs do not safe / do not write any files

Tags: c++, qt, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I recently started using virtualbox with ubuntu 20.04.  I am programming in QtCreator Qt 5.15.  But after switching to a virtual machine, I noticed that the programs don't save/write any files.  The necessary folders are open for reading, writing and execution for everyone.

What can prevent files from being written?

Comment: First of all, does the code check that opening the files succeeds? If not, what is the error they report? And are you trying to save files to the host system, or on the guest system? Where, and how, are you checking for the files?

Comment: Qt programs can write files. The issue is in your code. Please read about [mcve]